# Prevent freezing the UI when modify ListView?

Tags: c#, windows, listview, user-interface, blocking

I'm facing a problems when trying to modify the subitem's text of a ListView (about 20k records, virtual mode enabled = false).

```
list.BeginUpdate();

for(int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
{
   list.Items[i].SubItem[3].Text = "";
}

list.EndUpdate();
```

Inspite of using:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (s, e) => 
{
    list.BeginUpdate();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        list.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { list.Items[i].SubItem[3].Text = ""; }));
    }

    list.EndUpdate();
};

worker.RunWorkAsync();
```

Any helps are appreciated!

Comment: You are still using the ui element so you are using a background worker to call the ui thread every element, edit on a copy then copy the results back.. (better yet get a model to update!)

Comment: You can try to use list.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke but remember answer by xxbbcc is valid if you are doing calculation or some extensive work do that in background thread and only the updated section that deals with UI element wrap that code in delegate passed to BeginInvoke section.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend using a background thread to do this. The sole action your background thread takes is updating the UI so every call it makes is to the UI - there's nothing that really happens in the background that doesn't involve the UI.

Off the top of my head I can't think of anything that would make this faster than a straight `for` loop through all items. If anything, using the background thread makes things slower because each record update has to be invoked on the UI thread.

There may be a better solution that I don't think of now but I'd just do this:

```
list.BeginUpdate ();

for(int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
{
   list.Items[i].SubItem[3].Text = "";
}

list.EndUpdate ();
```

The [`BeginUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx) / [`EndUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate.aspx) functions can be used to suspend UI updates of the control while its data is being modified in bulk - this speeds up the loop considerably.

As an alternative, you can try updating a copy of the data shown in the list and then removing all items and adding the updated items using [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.addrange.aspx).

I'm not sure which solution would be faster (likely the direct update) but you should really consider either using a virtual list or showing fewer items in the list. Very few users can really deal with 20K records in a list - even scrolling through it must be a pain to find a specific item.

If you use `VirtualMode` you can keep all your data in your own list and only show items that actually fit in the window of the control. When you need to update the data, you only need to update your own copy of it and you'll only update those listview items that are shown on the UI, not the entire 20K set.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, I miss the Begin/End Update lines but the UI is still blocked for some secs.

Comment: @ByulTaeng Yes, I don't think you have much of a choice. You have too many items in the list and without virtual mode, you'll have to update every listview item. Begin/EndUpdate will only do so much.

Comment: The only option that won't cause freezing I believe is updating a model of data then updating the ui afterwards. I agree with xxbbcc though, 20k records is way too many for anyone to actually care to read at once

Comment: @Sayse: Because I'm using the Checkbox inside the ListView and normally it doesn't support Checkbox in virtual mode

Comment: That explains the data model, but can you not filter the results that are going into this?

Comment: @ByulTaeng In that case you can either create an owner-drawn list view (quite a bit of work) or cut down the number of items that need to be updated. I don't think you have any other choice. Virtual mode would benefit you in more than one way - faster updates and less memory used. (Right now you have your 20K records loded twice, I assume - one for your own list and then the items in the listview.)

Comment: @Sayse, no, it doesn't matter if you set values directly or by changing them via data binding to view model, you will still have to make 20k changes to UI. There is no workaround (except for data/UI virtualization).

Comment: Ok, then I think I have to use 3rd-party control, sth like ObjectListView. Really don't want to.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak - I never mentioned data binding

Comment: @ByulTaeng If you don't mind me asking, why are you showing so many items in the list? I can't imagine a user actually going through so many items at any time.

Comment: @xxbbcc: I'm writing a little application that download the chapter list of a list of manga from a website, then the user can select all the chapter in the list, download, the status of the downloading is displayed in the status column (like IDM).

Comment: @ByulTaeng In that case I'd definitely not show so many records - I assume there's no real pressure on you to do so. I'd probably add some filtering to search and only show up to maybe 500 records. If a user wants something different, either use paging or more specific search criteria. Showing the download status of so many items doesn't make much sense, either - the program will probably download 4-8 items at a given time.